# Could I use an older iMac as a second monitor for a Dell Latitude E7250 w/mini display port?

Tags: display, imac, thunderbolt

I have a 21.5" iMac from late 2009 that runs great. For work I have a Dell Latitude E7250 that has a mini display port. The mini-display port cable fits into the iMac but is this a "Thunderbolt" port and not really a mini-display port at all?? Are they the same thing?
If a had a mini display port to mini display port cable would I be able to use the iMac as the second monitor? 
Is that the correct cable? 
What keystrokes would I need to get this going?

Thanks in advance for your consideration of my question.

Answer (score 1):

The [Thunderbolt port can be used for Mini-DisplayPort](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204154). In theory, you should be able to use Target Display Mode because you are using a Windows machine as your primary display. [See [Use your iMac as a display with Target Display Mode](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT204592) and [How to transmit my PC onto my iMac?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147536/how-to-transmit-my-pc-onto-my-imac]). However, as mentioned in the latter link, you can use Microsoft Remote Desktop. Therefore, you could try using a Mini-DisplayPort to Mini-DisplayPort cable, but Microsoft Remote Desktop would be a safer bet.

Instructions for Target Display Mode:

Update: the Late '09 iMac **can accept Mini-DisplayPort connections**, so you should be able to use a Mini-DisplayPort cable.

> 1. Make sure Make sure both computers are turned on.
> 2. Connect the Mini DisplayPort or Thunderbolt cable between the two computers.
> 3. Press Command-F2 on the keyboard of the iMac that you want to use as a display.
> 4. To exit, press Command-F2 on the keyboard of the iMac that you want to use as a display.

(from https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592)

Instructions for Microsoft Remote Desktop:

> 1. Download the Remote Desktop Client from the Mac App Store.
> 2. Set up your remote PC to allow remote connections. (Allow Remote Access in Control Panel)
> 3. Create / Edit Remote Desktops, or add Remote Resources using the Remote Desktop client.
>
> Creating a Remote Desktop
>
> 1. On the Connection Center screen, click New.
> 2. In the Edit Remote Desktops window, enter information for the remote desktop connection
> 3. Click the close button to save the remote desktop.

(from https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn473012(v=ws.11).aspx)